# How can i convert unmanaged value type to managed type(like pointer to class)?

Tags: .net, marshalling

In .net, I have two class, like this:

```
class A
{
    public int a;
    public float b;
    public float foo()
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}

class B
{
    public static void Foo(A a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a.foo());
    }
}
```

The assembly code of the function B.Foo in the memory is as follows：

```
_asm
{
    push ebp;
    mov  ebp, esp;
    push edi;
    sub  esp, 4;
    mov  edi, [ebp + 8];    /// eid is Class A
    cmp  [edi], edi;
    mov  eax, [edi + 8];
    push eax;
    xxxxxx
    xxxxxx
    xxxxxx 
}
```

As we can see, edi is point to class A.
In some way, I got the value of edi, which is the ptr of Class A. Now i wanna convert edi to Class A.
If it is c++, i can do like this:
B *b = reinterpret_cast(edi);

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense, the edi register **is** a reference to the ClassA object.  So no conversion is ever needed.  The assembly code merely shows you how reference types work.  The `a` argument is a reference, not the actual object.  A pointer at runtime, it points into the GC heap.  One of the big jobs of the garbage collector is to update those pointers after it compacts the heap and moved objects in memory.

Comment: it is just a example, the edi register is a reference to the ClassA object in assembly code, the edi register is a int value in C#. I just wanna know is there any method convert int value to ClassA, when i got the value in assembly code and operate it by c#.

Comment: It is not an int, it is a pointer.  The distinction is very, very important in C#, that pointer value can change, an int can not.  If you ever try to do something like that then you'll inevitably corrupt memory when the GC can't change the int value.  You'll need to hit the books and learn why "pinning" is important.